# using unix login in jsp authentication

Tags: jsp, authentication, unix

I am using unix (AIX) in which I have installed apache-tomcat. In it, I have deployed an app using JSP. 
Now for authentication, I dont want to use the traditional database based authentication but instead want to use the same authentication that is used to login that unix box.

For eg:

```
A user logins a unix server using credentials : user1/password1
I wanted to use the same combination for my JSP login to access the app.
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible with JAASrealm. There is an example i a book called :"Tomcat: The Definitive Guide." by O`reilly.

Regards,